# zsh: command not found: msfconsole

Tags: terminal, zsh

Installed Metasploit on my macOS Catalina from the rapid7 website - `pkg` installation. When trying to run the command `msfconsole` the terminal displays the following error:

```
zsh: command not found: msfconsole
```

Comment: Where did you install it, which directories are in your `$PATH`?

Comment: @nohillside in my .profile I have these lines: `PATH=$PATH:/opt/metasploit-framework/binexport` and also `PATH=$PATH:/opt/metasploit-framework/bin`

Comment: What is the result of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: @nohillside `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: According to https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/mac-for-hackers-install-metasploit-framework-0174517/, it is located in `/opt/metasploit-framework/bin/`. Could you check it and report back?

Comment: @jaume This is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zsh uses .zprofile in your home directory

Try copying the contents of .profile to .zprofile and then launch a new terminal window

Comment: I didnt have `.zprofile` in my home directory, I created a new text document and named it `.zprofile` copied the contents of `.profile` and it worked! Thank you.